# sentences with "would rather"

Tags: sentence-construction

I have a question
 I would die rather than marry/marrying him.
marry or marrying , which one would be better in this context or either of them ?

I don't have native ears , so please help me with this!

Please, Explain the rule[if exists] behind it, so that I can decide on my own in future and don't trouble you people with such trivial things.

Comment: "_I would rather die than to marry him_"

Comment: What was wrong with my sentences ? Could you please explain  ?

Comment: I think that in "would rather A than B", A and B should match. "I would rather be **eating** cake than **blowing out** candles." "I would rather **eat** than **drink**."  I don't know if that is a grammatical rule or just good style. See [Parallelism (grammar)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(grammar)) on Wikipedia for more explanation.

Comment: would rather cannot be followed by ing. It requires a verb, either passive or active.

Comment: @Lambie: Aside from a gerund.

Comment: @Dan No, it cannot be followed by a verb ending in ING. Must one always have to spell out every little tiny thing to be understood?? So, no, not "aside from a gerund". NOT a gerund.

Comment: Would rather A than B reads **would rather A than would B**. Consequently A and B should be bare infinitives.

Comment: @Lambie "I would rather eating than fasting" is a valid sentence in this form, using gerunds.

Comment: Listen guys! yesterday , I watched pride and prejudice and came across this  solution.... whenever you feel like confused .......say "I would prefer eating  rather than fasting ? " ...or..  I would eat rather than fasting..... What's your opinion on this. Kindly, let me know

Comment: @Dan No, |I would rather eating than fasting| is not valid. |I would rather be eating than fasting.| the ing cannot come after |would rather|. |I would prefer| is not |I would rather|. Prefer takes ING or TO. That is, a bare infinitive or a to + infinitive.

Comment: @Lambie It's perfectly valid sentence, with noun gerunds. Any other sentence with nouns is valid too, see my answer.

Comment: @Lambie Though, of course, you would normally hear the form you suggest.

Comment: @Dan It is not at all usual. Only perhaps in response to a question. I'd rather playing tennis than playing pool. It sounds very awkward.

Comment: @Lambie Admittedly it sounds awkward, yes. Though I still hear it occasionally, usually where there's an implied verb. "I'd rather [go] playing tennis than playing pool." A side effect of English laziness probably.

Comment: @Dan, You tried to answer Lambie and me at the same time while doing so you mixed up the whole sentence and I couldn't understand what  you were trying to say.... " i would prefer eating rather than fasting" Is it wrong?? ..........and what about "I would eat rather than fasting"?

Comment: @SharmaPocso The most common form is "I would rather eat than fast." I was arguing that "I would rather eating than fasting" is rarer but still heard. Similarly, you might hear both "I would prefer to eat rather than fast" and "I would prefer eating rather than fasting."

Answer (score 2):

The form you want is:

> I would rather die than marry him.

This form uses "I would rather [infinitive] than [infinitive]." Another example:

> I would rather walk than drive.

However you can also "rather" nouns:

> I would rather a coffee than a milkshake.